# date format with adobe flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I have a date and I would like to format the date like that:
YYYYMMDD HHMMSS
so for today it's
20100304 173000

But when I'm doing this:

```
var todayStr:String = today.getFullYear()+today.getMonth()+today.getDay()+today.getHours()+today.getMinutes();
```

the problem is for March getMonth() sent "3" and I would like "03". There is the same problem with the day.

How I can do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a DateFormatter. Have a look at this : [Dateformatter @ adobe](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/formatters/DateFormatter.html)

```
var formatter : DateFormatter;
formatter = new DateFormatter();
formatter.formatString = "YYYYMMDD HHNNSS";
formatter.format(dateInstance);
```

beware of the 'N' used for the minutes

Answer (score 1):

Try a simple function like:

```
private function formatTwoDigits(val:Number) : String {
  var retVal:String = "";
  retVal = (val > 9) ? val.toString() : "0" + val.toString();
  return retVal;
}
```

Then use as:

```
var month:String = formatTwoDigits(today.getMonth()+1); // add 1 because months are zero-based
```

Answer (score 0):

While there's probably an easier way you can just do this more procedurally.

```
var todayStr:String;

todayStr+=today.getFullYear();

if(today.getMonth()<10){
  todayStr+="0";
  todayStr+=today.getMonth();
}else{
  todayStr+=today.getMonth();
}
```

etc.